# How to determine order statistics for jQuery object

Tags: jquery

With my HTML `select` there are four or five options. Is there an easier way to find out which ordinal number describes each option element ? If so, what is the statement ?

I thought about creating creating a mapped array with option values as indexes but that doesn't seem too efficient.

I just need the counting number.

Comment: Where would the numbers be set/positioned? Could you write a small example for us please?

Comment: @Ghillied The [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dnBm8/) that user Andy gave is the functionality I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though it's a bit hacky, you could try something like this:

### HTML

```
<select>
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c">C</option>
    <option value="d">D</option>
</select>
```

### JavaScript/jQuery

```
$('select').change(function(){
    var $option = $(this).find('option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]') ;
    alert($option.index());
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dnBm8/)

Comment: Slightly less hacky - `$(':selected', this).index()`

Comment: @Andy the jsFiddle worked well, thank you. I would recommend adding a double quote like this though: `$(this).find('option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]');`. The option value in my script was a path so adding the double quote inside single quote worked better.